# Adding write to log using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, reflector, reflexil

I'm trying to use Reflexil to log a string in an existing method in a dll I haven't got the source code to.
The problem is, I can add a method that uses System.IO because I'm trying to add it to a dll that didn't use file writing before and can't add references.

Is there some log writing command that is accessible through System.dll I can use?

Comment: All `System.IO.File.*` methods are located in mscorlib.dll and are useable without new references.

Comment: @thehennyy That's weird then. It might have to do with reflexil not letting any usage of external members, but for some reason it does work with their code editor

Comment: Even the basic assemblies mscorlib.dll and System.dll have to be loaded into the decompiler, then the reflexil ui should let you select methods from these assemblies.

Comment: @thehennyy I didn't find any way to load it
It's funny because the code editor window of reflexil has some kind of intelisense which does recognize these function

Comment: I am using reflexil in JustDecompile and i have to load other assemblies into JustDecompile first to create references in reflexil to them.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial solution to the problem

I modified the original constructor to a normal method
Created a new constructor and matched the signature then called the new method with the addition of the logging code

For now this compiles, but for some reason the exe crashes the second it starts

Comment: So now I tried it again with some simpler code and it worked
The WriteAllTextMethod crashes the application for some reason

Comment: The problem was trying to write to C, so my solution works